# How to show count of data in pie-chart in chartkick rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, highcharts, chartkick

I want to show count of data along with percentage.It works but for small percentages nothing appear due to small size.Is it possible to show count and percentage outside chart.Or where list  of interests along with them.

```
<%= pie_chart users.joins(:relationship_status).group('relationship_statuses.name').count, library: {legend: {labelFormat: '{name} : {y} ({percentage:.1f}%)'}} %>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can show them in legends. The list where you are showing legends you can put % of each. to do so :

```
    legend: {
    labelFormat: '{name} : {y} ({percentage:.1f}%)',
     layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right'

  },
```

See [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/9wXvr/30/)

Comment: I write query in question

Comment: You are using highcharts and I am using chartkicks